# Syntax tree for this sentence

Tags: computational-linguistics, syntax-trees

I am trying to find best way to get a syntax tree for this sentence:

*Planting seeds helps you grow your farm*

I thought of this:

```
          -------- S1 ---------
          |                  |
     --- NP ---          -- VP --
     |        |          |   |   |
     N        N          V1   NP  S2


          -------- S2 ---------
          |                    |
          VP              -- NP --
          |               |       |
          V2              Det     N
```

where:

```
  S1 is: Planting seeds helps you
  S2: grow your farm
  N's: Planting, seeds, garden
  V1 : helps
  V2 : grow
  Det : your
  NP (=N): you
```

Does this tree make sense?

Comment: No, it makes no sense at all, and your sentence is somewhat odd too, since we don't talk of growing a farm! Are you asking for a tree from us?

Comment: I am trying to find a tree for senseless sentences such as this.

Comment: it's similar with something like: "Drinking water nourishes you start your diet"

Comment: @feijao That sentence makes no sense. The one in the question does make sense, but your analysis is wrong as it is only one sentence, not two. What syntax framework are you working under?

Comment: I've drawn a tree using the basic system, not the awful x-bar stuff! This is a catenative construction, where "help" is a catenative verb and the subordinate clause "grow your farm" is its catenative complement ('cat'). The intervening noun "you" is the syntactic object of "help", and the _understood_ subject of "grow".

Answer (score 2):

[image: 1]]

Simplified tree diagram of:

"Planting seeds helps you grow your farm."

Comment: why should planting be a verb?

Comment: @feijao Because it has "seeds" as direct object, and only verbs have direct objects.